# jquery issue in loading a new page into a div with animation

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am looking to have a div, which holds a php page to fade out, unload, and then fade in a new page on every menu:

```
        $('#home').click(function() {
        $('#page_container').fadeOut(500).unload();
        $('#page_container').load('php/home.php').fadeIn(550);
    });
```

For some reason, it flickers the new page, before it fades out in the first instance, fades out and reloads.

Could someone please help me with this.  I am sure it's simple, but I cannot seem to find the right syntax to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the `load()` call to occur in the callback of the fade function:

```
$("#home").on("click", function () {
    $('#page_container').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $(this).unload();
        $(this).load('php/home.php');
    });
})
```

This will fire `load()` once the fade is completed.

`fadeOut()` is asynchronous, and so the next line is executed immediately after it is called. Your problem is caused because `load()` is loading content into your div immediately as it starts to fade out.

Comment: Great, just be sure to click the check box if this best answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Without a demo it's hard to fully understand, but have you looked at using callbacks?

```
$('#home').click(function() {
    $('#page_container').fadeOut(500, function(){ 
        $(this).unload(); 
        $('#page_container').load('php/home.php', function(){ 
            $(this).fadeIn(550) 
        });
    });

});
```